# What makes for a good cable modem?

Tags: internet, cable-modem

I'm tired of renting my cable modem and am wondering how to tell them apart.
Some are 1/2 the price of others yet they all seem the same. What are the criteria one should look for when purchasing a cable modem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say the following three are the most important, in my opinion:

1. [DOCSIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOCSIS) version supported. Version 3.0 supports higher speeds (and multiple channels), as well as IPv6. I had to upgrade my modem because my older one (DOCSIS 2.0) couldn't be used for 50mbps cable broadband.
2. Support by your cable company. Ask them what they support and/or recommend. If you get something they don't support, your cable company will blame your modem for every problem you get with your broadband...
3. Level of support/warranty from the modem's manufacturer. This is a personal preference of course.